# Is there a way in excel to highlight a row, only if one condition is true and another condition is false?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have done quite a bit of searching on this, and have found a way to set up nearly every kind of formatting rule except for this specific case. I need an entire row of the table to be highlighted only when two different conditions are present. The two conditions are:

## 1 cell in column E does not contain “text 1”

## 2 cell in column H does contain “text 2”

I need the whole table (upwards of a few thousand rows, by 12-ish columns) to be considered, and I can’t modify any of the data in the tables, or the sheets themselves.

After some playing around with solutions to similar but different problems, I ended up with a formula that seems like it should work... the logic seems right, and I’m pretty sure the syntax is correct also, but when I add the formula to the conditional formatting rule, nothing happens. It accepts the formula, but it just does nothing.

I tested it out by applying the formula to a simple test sheet and put it in column C, and it results in “TRUE” being in column C when the conditions are present, and “FALSE” being in column C when one or both of them are not present, which seems like it’s behaving correctly. Any tips would be appreciated!

Here’s what I have currently:

> =AND(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(“*text 1*”, $E1), 0),FALSE,TRUE),IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(“*text 2*”, $H1),0),TRUE,FALSE))

(Edit: there are asterisks before and after the “text 1” and “text 2”, inside the quotes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a formula in CF you must produce a formula which evaluates to either TRUE or FALSE, as in

```
=AND(ISERROR(SEARCH("text 1", $E1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text 2", $H1)))
```

Comment: This seems to work - thank you! But to make sure I understand what was wrong, are you able to explain why what I had wasn’t working?

Comment: Apologies, I think your formula should work, although it's unnecessarily complicated. Were you actually using the "curly" quote marks rather than straight ones?

Comment: if the problem is not the quote marks, the problem might have been relative references. As your formula references row 1 you need to select row 1 first when adding it.

Comment: Standard quotes, I suppose I didn’t copy the code into my post correctly. I noticed in your formula you just have quotes, and no asterisks surrounding the substring, but I made that edit and mine still didn’t work. I’m a little perplexed what I got wrong, aside from the overcomplication.